# row in UITableViewCell just show the first index array from USGS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i'm trying to fetch data from USGS earthquake with AFNetworking framework with filter region Korea. i've problem to show data in method tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath. count of row in tableview is same with count of data earthquake, but the problem is why data just show the first earthquake from Korea.

this is my code for method tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath :

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    EarthquakeViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSArray *earthquakeFeaturesData = [self.earthquakeDataService features];

    int indexEarthquake = 0;
    for ( NSDictionary *earthquakeData in earthquakeFeaturesData){
        if ([[earthquakeData title] containsString:@"California"]){
            NSString *stringDate = [Helper convertMilisecondsToReadableStringDate:[earthquakeData updated]];
            cell.placeLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", GLOBAL_FONT_TYPE] size:14];
            cell.placeLabel.text =[earthquakeData place];
            cell.magLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", GLOBAL_FONT_TYPE] size:25];
            cell.magLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", earthquakeData.mag];
            cell.mLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", GLOBAL_FONT_TYPE] size:13];
            cell.mLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Magnitude"];
            cell.timeLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", GLOBAL_FONT_TYPE] size:14];
            cell.timeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ", stringDate];

            NSLog(@"%@", earthquakeData.mag);
            indexEarthquake++;
            NSLog(@"%i", indexEarthquake)
        }
    }

    return cell;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if(!self.earthquakeDataService)
        return 0;
    else{
        NSArray *earthquakeFeaturesData = [self.earthquakeDataService features];
        int indexEarthquake = 0;
        for ( NSDictionary *earthquakeData in earthquakeFeaturesData){
            if ([[earthquakeData title] containsString:@"California"]){
                indexEarthquake++;
            }
        }
        NSLog(@"%i",indexEarthquake);
        return indexEarthquake;
    }
}
```

I think the problem is cause i need array to save temporary data from USGS and present it after iteration. so, how to fix this problem??

Comment: FYI - why do you use a `for` loop in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`? If you just want to show data for California, create an array with just that data once (in `viewDidLoad`?). Then use that array as your table's data source.

Answer (score 1):

cellForRowAtIndexPath is called once for every cell in your table view. You do the same thing every time it is called, starting at index 0 and iterating throught your data. Because of that all your cells contain the same data. You should use the indexPath to select which data to use. It would probably be easier if you started out filtering the data before loading into the tableview instead of trying to do so on the fly.